# How to restrict ssh access only to users within multiple groups?

Tags: ssh, access-control-list

I would like to know how to allow ssh access to users who are in multiple groups.  For example, in general, if the user is part of the group `shell` then they may access a number of servers.  However, I only want a small subset of `shell` users to have shell access to the web server.  Therefore, I want the web server only to allow users who are both in `shell` and `web` groups.  `admin` users are always allowed.  I thought, after reading the sshd_config(5) manual and ssh_config(5) PATTERNS section, something like this would work:

`AllowGroups admin shell,web`

I guess I'm misunderstanding patterns and pattern-lists because this isn't working as intended and *sshd* is saying "not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups" but `id user` shows they are a member of `shell` and `web` groups.

Is using `Match` the correct approach?  For example:

```
Match Group admin
  AllowGroups admin

Match Group shell,web
  AllowGroups shell web
```

Thanks